# Should "LLC" be included on the sign on my business front door (California)?

Tags: corporate-law

Does California require that I append ", LLC" to my business name for the letters silkscreened on the front door of my business, or the building directory facing the street?

Things I've read online suggest yes, but none were California-specific.

My landlord recently silkscreened my name on the door, and didn't add the LLC. I need to ask them to re-do it if that's the case.